# How to implement two of the same method in a single class

Tags: vb.net

I have a Class, BettingAgency, and two instances TAB and Ladbrokes. Trouble is, whilst they have the same method signatures, the methods for each are implemented differently. I do not want to implement the instances as separate classes as I have a DataGrid that maintains a list of BettingAgencies. Seemingly a very common need. Is there a solution to my problem within  VB.NET.

I have a solution to this problem. One of the methods I am referring to above is GetMeetings. TAB and Ladbrokes provide Web API's to do so, each slightly different. I have created classes TAB.vb and Ladbroke.vb specifically to handle the WEb APIs with an inherited class of BettingAPIs. I also have a Meetings class with a Sub New that I pass a BettingAPIs object to (TAb or Ladbrokes). So I create my meetings within the New Sub of Meetngs by calling BettingAPIs.GetMeetings.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. If you have methods that are implemented differently, you're not talking about instances of a class. You have a parent class with two children that inherit from it. "Instance" means something different.

Comment: That is the problem, I don't want children. I want a BettingAgencies collection containing BettingAgency objects and each BettingAgency object contains the same properties and method signatures but a different implementation of the methods for each object.

Comment: With that description, children is **exactly** what you want. A collection of the parent type (bettingagency) can hold objects of the child type (tab and ladbrokes), which will have all the properties, but methods can be overridden for different behaviors..

Comment: I think your use case is reasonably well solved by subclassing; it sounds like you don't know how to create instances of classes based on information known at creation time. For that, a Factory Method may suffice. However, there are methods for substituting behavior after creation (delegates, in C#, are one; others might include the Strategy or State patterns). I see no reason for anything that complex at this point; your problem seems to be about instantiation of an appropriate class.

An adapter object that translates the API call depending on the type may also fit.

Comment: Definitely don't want child classes as I have only one instance per child class. One of the purposes of a class is to provide for multiple instances. As I say, this is an extremely common pattern that could be handled by a language construct but is not (that I am aware of)

Answer (score 2):

From an OOP standpoint, you should make BettingAgency a base class and have TAB and Ladbrokes both extend it. Then each can share all the model/view/control attributes of the parent class, but you override the methods or getters that need to work differently. So you might have a function called scrapeSite() which is overridden in all the child classes, but everything else is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can overload methods in VB.NET

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973896.aspx

So by passing in different parameters you can get them to do different things while maintaining the method signature.

You should be able to achieve what you want by doing so, however the more correct way of doing thins would be by creating a base class and extending that class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x4yd9d5(v=vs.90).aspx

Doing so will allow you to override the methods for more specific classes.

Answer (score 0):

Does your method have the sender object:

```
 public void myMethod(object sender, Event Args e){
if (sender.someproperty == "TAB") do something...
}
```

if not just add a custom var:

```
 public void myMethod(whoSentIt){
if(whosentIt == "Tab") do something...
}
```

Comment: It would seem this extremely common pattern is not implemented in any language. I am going to go with

Public class BettingAgency
.
.
.


public function getMeetings() as Meetings

   if AgencyType = "Ladbrokes"
        do somethng
   else
        do something else 

Sorry seems I can add line in a comment. Not sure either how to reply!

Comment: I could use CallByName to call TABGetMeetings, LadbrokesGetMeetings etc. Or I could use namespaces Namespace TAb GetMeetings Namespace Ladbrokes GetMeetings but it is fairly inflexible.